# Make twitter Login with codebird.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, twitter

im trying to make a twitter login via javascript with codebird.js

i don't know how can i get the userid, name and other info of the user after login and control if the session is active.
i started with this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var cb = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey("uGpF9dGap2nvIplIz0sIor2UH", "M9lEpsOyrEiyz0tjJ2uERWGZIWEEg681KdJBTzk3UhRnUpTCgf");
//cb.setToken("403332774-Fn288SA96MuJnd6OzMyRWtjLyoZ509TLiLwTv6pl", "XyMg5eHaf5ahQHKle72EPruXgJx4ifUq2VAmG1j5xCbnD");

$('#login').click(function(){
cb.__call(
        "oauth_requestToken",
        {oauth_callback: "oob"},
        function (reply) {
            // stores it
            cb.setToken(reply.oauth_token, reply.oauth_token_secret);

            // gets the authorize screen URL
            cb.__call(
                    "oauth_authorize",
                    {},
                    function (auth_url) {
                           window.open(auth_url,"MsgWindow",'height=202,width=800');
                    }
            );
        }
);
 });

 </script>
```

the html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head lang="en">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1 id="login">login twitter</h1>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/libs/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 <script src="../js/libs/codebird.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

the oauth_authorize callback can return a response where i can get the user info?

Comment: Did you find the solution .... i stuck on the same stage.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a pin page where you input the pin u get after auth_authorize..the screen_name and other credentials are part of the response you get from the server to show you are fully authorized.
**P.S: Do not set the token you generated as the token for authentication/ authorization, except you want people to post tweets on behalf of the account which created the twitter application.**

Comment: caps ain't that beautiful